# How to make frida wait for classes to load via DexPathList?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

When I run my frida script, I get this error:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.classname" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

But I do not get this error if I change the value **10** to something bigger:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    Java.performNow(function() {
        traceClass("com.example.classname");
    });
}, 10);
```

*traceClass - a function that makes `Java.use` on a class and enumerates their methods, adding implementations, etc.*

As I understand, the class I want to trace is not in the main **DexPathList** or something like this. It just fails to load on time I call this class in frida.

Is there a way to access a class after it's loaded but before being called by anyone else? I want to implement its functions before they are called by other classes.

Comment: You can try to hook the class loader itself, methods like findClass or something like this. The you will see when the class is loaded you are interested in.

Comment: Which type of class are you trying to load? An Android OS class or an app class?

If its an app class you can hook Android OS. If you're looking at Android OS its a little more difficult.